# Python: Concatenate Hour into dd/mm/yyyy column in data file

Tags: python, date, time, time-series, datestamp

I have the following file:

```
01/03/2019,23,24.0
01/03/2019,22,24.5
01/03/2019,21,25.9
01/03/2019,20,26.4
01/03/2019,19,26.6
01/03/2019,18,25.9
```

Where column 1 is date (dd/mm/yyyy), column 2 is hour and column 3 is temperature.

How can I merge columns 1 and 2 in order to make a new column dd/mm/yyyy hh:00, by using pyhton?

I am using a .csv file and pandas module.

Comment: Merge where? Is this using pandas or just python? What have you tried?

Comment: Without your relevant code to give us context, it's virtually impossible for us to give you any advice. Please update your post.

Comment: Use csv in order to read it, merge what you need to merge and use csv in order to write new file. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html

Comment: @roganjosh using pandas

Comment: @JordanSinger ok, I'll edit it based the comments above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using csv OR pandas library (tested using python 3.7)

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

use_pandas = True

if use_pandas:
    df = pd.read_csv('55089401.csv', header=None)
    df[3] = df[0].map(str) + ' ' + df[1].map(str) + ':00'
    del df[0]
    del df[1]
    new_order = [1, 0]
    df = df[df.columns[new_order]]
    print(df)
else:
    out_data = []
    with open('55089401.csv', 'r') as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        for row in reader:
            out_data.append(['{} {}:00'.format(row[0], row[1]), row[2]])
    with open('55089401_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
        writer = csv.writer(f_out)
        writer.writerows(out_data)
```

Pandas output

```
0  01/03/2019 23:00  24.0
1  01/03/2019 22:00  24.5
2  01/03/2019 21:00  25.9
3  01/03/2019 20:00  26.4
4  01/03/2019 19:00  26.6
5  01/03/2019 18:00  25.9
```

Input file

```
01/03/2019,23,24.0
01/03/2019,22,24.5
01/03/2019,21,25.9
01/03/2019,20,26.4
01/03/2019,19,26.6
01/03/2019,18,25.9
```

Output file (csv)

```
01/03/2019 23:00,24.0
01/03/2019 22:00,24.5
01/03/2019 21:00,25.9
01/03/2019 20:00,26.4
01/03/2019 19:00,26.6
01/03/2019 18:00,25.9
```

Comment: the code worked fine. When I plotted by using matplotlib, the chart appears inverted

Comment: This is a different issue. I think you should create a new post and introduce the plot problem

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the lines in the input file, and output with the appended column

```
with open('filename.csv') as fin:
    for inputLine in fin:
        x = inputLine.split(',')
        outputLine = inputLine + ',' + str(x[0]) + ' ' + str(x[1]) + ':00'
```